# What code can I use to prompt users in Java?

Tags: java

Please help me to solve this problem, because I'm just to new to java and I don't know how to code this...tnx

Comment: If you are new to Java, then you should start by reading the [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: In what context?  A swing application, a webapp, a console-launched processing app?  Also, are you prompting for arbitrary input, prompting with information, or prompting for a yes/no decision?

Comment: I'm prompting to ask users to input anything, like if I ask users to input their name then after they hit the enter key their name will be printed...tnx

Answer (score 5):

You can try like this to prompt users to enter values.

```
    public static void main(String a[]) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter name : ");
     String name =input.nextLine();
     System.out.println(" name --  "+name);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Swing you can use this

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your Name");
System.out.println(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean print messages on screen? The default way to do this is by using System.out:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome at my program.");
            System.out.println("'println' will print on new lines.");
            System.out.print("Whereas 'print' will");
            System.out.print(" stay at the same line!");
}
```

Would output:

```
    Welcome at my program.
    Whereas 'print' will stay at the same line!
```

Look for more info on the Java API: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out

Comment: If I coded asking the user, " Please type your Name: ", after thatthe user will be able to type his/her name...tnx

Comment: Do it like so: Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(); System.out.println("Please type your Name:"); String name = keyboard.nextline();